# Concatenate torch tensor at a certain index

Tags: python-3.x, concatenation, torch

I am looking to Concatenate 2 torch tensors at a certain index. As an example, I want to add b after a[1].

```
a = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = torch.Tensor([6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

The desired output is

```
torch.Tensor([1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 4, 5])
```

I tried `torch.cat`, but I can only have

```
tensor([ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
tensor([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.])
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to split the first tensor and concatenate the second in between

```
torch.cat([a[:2], b, a[2:]])
```

output will be like

```
tensor([ 1.,  2.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```